# Creating a new TLD for private network

Tags: dns, bind

I want to setup a new TLD (`foo.`) for my the private network so that I can host some child domains which will be accessible from within the network. For this purpose I have setup a DNS server (172.16.100.1) for `foo.`. For this I created a zone file `foo-zonedb.rr` with the following records:

```
$ORIGIN foo.
$TTL  100
@       IN  SOA ns1.tld.foo. hostmaster.tld.foo (
                2012030701
                900
                300
                300
                600
        )
@    300 IN NS ns1.tld.foo.
@    300 IN  A 172.16.143.197
ns1.tld.foo.    300 IN A 172.16.143.197
```

And also I have added the following entries in `/etc/named.conf`

```
zone "foo." {
             type master;
             file "foo-zonedb.rr";
             notify explicit;
    };
```

Now suppose every machine on the network uses `172.16.1.1` as their DNS server. What configuration should I have to do on `172.16.1.1` so that it won't redirect DNS request for `foo.` domain to root DNS servers?

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-for-private-networks for a discussion about why using a made up TLD is possibly a bad idea.

Comment: @TimKennedy: but i am talking about the configuration details..the discussion on the link which u provided is totally offtopic

Comment: ok.  just wanted to make sure you're aware of the gotcha's involved in hosting a private TLD connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

`type master;` does what you want.  if `172.16.1.1` is the authoritative server, requests will not go to the root servers.  Non-existent entries will result in NXDOMAIN status.

If you want to stop **all** queries from forwarding to the root-servers, then you should turn recursion off.  see: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/#authoritative

Answer (score 0):

You could have clients configured to use 172.16.100.1 as their primary DNS server.

Use the forwarding option in bind to 172.16.1.1 on your DNS server at 172.16.100.1.

```
options {
         [Your other options here]
         forwarders {172.16.1.1;};
}
```

The first Authoritive response will be returned (wins). So your clients look up

something.foo

Your DNS server will provide an authoritive response (either a valid record or NXDOMAIN). If your client searches for www.google.com - your DNS server cannot provide a response and as a result will forward the request to 172.16.1.1.

I use custom TLD's for everything on my internal networks. With the above configuration, it works without any issues and still allows public DNS resolution via the forwarding option.